# Class requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.app.ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: android, compatibility

my app has a actionbar and fragments. i use tablistener for tabs to action bar:

```
package com.infomercados.appinfomercados;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.util.Log;

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public TabListener(Fragment fg)
    {
        this.fragment = fg;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " reselected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " selected.");
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Log.i("ActionBar", tab.getText() + " no selected.");
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
```

i want to adapt for early versions and i added the android-support-v6-appcompat.jar but produces this error:
Class requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.app.ActionBar.TabListener

Can you help me?

Very Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You are not using the Classes of Support library.

For example:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

**Regarding ActionBar:**

If you are using AppCompat library then you need to import:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
```

If you are using ActionBarSherLock library then you need to import:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
```

Comment: If it has helped you then you should up vote/accept it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the support library version of the class. Import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` instead of `android.app.ActionBar` to fix this particular issue. (While there, change your other `android.app` imports too since e.g. fragments are not there in API level 7.)

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is, use support library, like:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```